# Who are the moderators of Bitcoin dev mailing list and how are they selected?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-development

Looking for names of all moderators and what was the process to select them as moderator

Comment: On the process I think like many things in Bitcoin history it was whoever volunteered :) Ideally they would have long standing reputation in the community which they all do.

Answer (score 0):

Moderators:

1. [Ruben Somsen](https://gist.github.com/RubenSomsen/c9f0a92493e06b0e29acced61ca9f49a)
2. [Bryan Bishop](https://twitter.com/kanzure)

Sometimes moderated by [Kalle Alm](https://twitter.com/kallewoof) and [Warren Togami](https://twitter.com/wtogami) based on information shared by Ruben.

I am not sure who selected them as moderators but here's some information about it: https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2016-October/013201.html